# How to get zero count for missing dates in mysql group by clause

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a mysql table from which i need to find how many records created per day in last 30 days.

A simple query for that is like

`select count(*) from table_name where date(created) > yyyymmdd group by date(created) order by date(created)`

I don't require to select date here, just the counts.

So i expect 30 rows here.
But the problem here is if there are no records created on some day, it will not appear in the result and I'll have less than 30 rows.

Is there any other way to print zero (0) count for the dates where no records are created ?

current output :

```
+---------------+----------+
| date(created) | count(*) |
+---------------+----------+
| 2019-12-20    |     1504 |
| 2019-12-29    |       12 |
+---------------+----------+
```

Expected output :

```
+---------------+----------+
| date(created) | count(*) |
+---------------+----------+
| 2019-12-20    |     1504 |
| 2019-12-21    |        0 |
| 2019-12-22    |        0 |
| 2019-12-23    |        0 |
| 2019-12-24    |        0 |
| 2019-12-25    |        0 |
| 2019-12-26    |        0 |
| 2019-12-27    |        0 |
| 2019-12-28    |        0 |
| 2019-12-29    |       12 |
+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: Add sample data and expected result

Comment: added @Jens. please check.

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this :

```
SET @date_min = '2019-12-20';
SET @date_max = '2019-12-29';

SELECT
   date_generator.date as the_date,
   IFNULL(COUNT(table_name.id), 0) as count
from (
   select DATE_ADD(@date_min, INTERVAL (@i:=@i+1)-1 DAY) as `date`
   from information_schema.columns,(SELECT @i:=0) gen_sub 
   where DATE_ADD(@date_min,INTERVAL @i DAY) BETWEEN @date_min AND @date_max
) date_generator
left join `table_name` on DATE(created) = date_generator.date
GROUP BY date;
```

so here I am creating a temporary table date_generator will dates in between of given date range and join to with your main table (transactions).

output as expected:

```
+---------------+----------+
| the_date      | count    |
+---------------+----------+
| 2019-12-20    |     1504 |
| 2019-12-21    |        0 |
| 2019-12-22    |        0 |
| 2019-12-23    |        0 |
| 2019-12-24    |        0 |
| 2019-12-25    |        0 |
| 2019-12-26    |        0 |
| 2019-12-27    |        0 |
| 2019-12-28    |        0 |
| 2019-12-29    |       12 |
+---------------+----------+
```

Comment: Hello @Ronak, how I can get the same result but by username. In the table there is a column username, so want to get the same result for an specific user, thanks in advance.

Comment: @Speego could please provide sample input and output for better understanding?

Answer (score 0):

Test:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
cte AS ( SELECT @yyyymmdd + INTERVAL 1 DAY dateCreated 
         UNION ALL
         SELECT dateCreated + INTERVAL 1 DAY
         FROM cte
         WHERE dateCreated < ( SELECT MAX(DATE(created))
                               FROM table_name ) )
SELECT COUNT(table_name.created) 
FROM cte
JOIN table_name ON DATE(table_name.created) = cte.dateCreated 
GROUP BY cte.dateCreated 
ORDER BY cte.dateCreated
```

`@yyyymmdd` is a variable or placeholder where the value from the condition of your query (`where date(created) > yyyymmdd`) must be specified.